# How to change layout by clicking items of menu?

Tags: java, android, layout, menu

I'm trying to enable users to change layout of my apps.

This is my XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menuTheme"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Theme">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/themeBlack"
            android:title="Black" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/themeWhite"
            android:title="White" />
    </menu>
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menuAbout"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="About" />
```

Here are the screenshots from my emulator: 
This is my menu.

[image: This is my menu.]

After clicking the item Theme under the menu, this submenu will appear.
[image: After clicking the item Theme under the menu, this submenu will appear]

Lets say i wish to add a white layout, where and how should i add codes?I have a XML file named themewhite.XML in the res/layout folder. I tried to add a switch in the item theme but it doesn't seemed to be correct.

This is my code:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.menuTheme:
        {
            switch(item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.themeWhite;
                {
                    setContentView(R.layout.themewhite);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case R.id.menuAbout:
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't want to set new layout, you want change just visualisation of existing.

If so you should manilpuate with themes of your activity. For first you need to create themes (white and so on) and decalre views attributes with using values from style. And then in your listener after click one of items, you should change your theme by calling
`getContext().setTheme(resid)`

Here a good article about themes http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html